# Tab App (FB) wont show on Facebook iPhone App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a facebook and placed it on my facebook brand page, I also created a post on the wall of that page with the link to the app.

all works well until people started calling me saying that when accessing using FB iPhone app it will redirect to an error page "the page your requested was not found"

I tried adding a link (same page) to the "Mobile Web" link of my app in the FB Developer App.

it still doesn't work..

I need people accessing the app page to get some content.. I know it is possible but cant find how..

thanks for your help

Comment: Is your application in sandbox mode? Check your application settings.  If sandbox mode is on then only people listed as developers/testers/etc will be able to get to your application

Comment: no, sandbox mode is disabled..

Comment: Page Tab apps are not supported on mobile. Similar Q here - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10342182/1628782

Comment: true. but I posted on the page wall a direct link to the app itself, but this link is the one that produces this error..

Answer (score 0):

Tabs aren't supported via the app or mobile site. Best you could do is add the query parameter "ref=ts" to prevent the page from going switching to mobile. It helps in the browser but not the app itself.

So add ?ref=ts to the end of your app url and at least mobile users can see it in their browser.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10833366/461119